# error: 'attribute value must be constant' for attribute's value = Class

Tags: java

I have some class, where I need have a annotation with parameter's type 'Class':

```
@ClassEntry(InformationPage)
public class LossInformation {...}
```

where `InformationPage` - name of class.

When I use the above line of code, I get a 'attribute value must be constant' error. Why? What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try InformationPage.class instead of InformationPage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `@ClassEntry(InformationPage.class)` instead of just InformationPage